# Universally measurable sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

$$\text{Is }{{\cal B}(\mathbb{R}^2})^u={{\cal B}(\mathbb{R}})^u\times {{\cal B}(\mathbb{R}})^u\,?\tag1$$

Is the $\sigma$-algebra of [universally measurable sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_measurable_set) on $\mathbb{R}^2$ equal to the 
product $\sigma$-algebra of two copies of the universally measurable sets on $\mathbb{R}$? It is not hard
to see that (1) is true with $\supseteq$ instead of $=$,
and I would be astonished if (1) were true, but I'm not sure.

Has anyone encountered this problem, or know a reference that might help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you expected, the answer to your question is negative.

Recall that a set $U \subset X \times Y$ is *universal* for a class $\Gamma \subset \mathcal{P}(Y)$ if for every $G \in \Gamma$ there is $x \in X$ such that $G$ is the vertical section $U_x$ of $U$, that is:  $G = U_x = \{ y \in Y : (x,y) \in U\}$. Recall also that [analytic sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) are universally measurable.

One standard way to prove that there are analytic sets in $X$ that aren't Borel sets is to exhibit an analytic set $U \subset X \times X$ which is universal for the analytic sets in $X$. The set of diagonal points $D = \{x \in X: (x,x) \in U\}$ of $U$ turns out to be an analytic set which is not Borel. The proof is a diagonal argument reminiscent of the Russell paradox and of Cantor's $\kappa \lt 2^\kappa$-theorem. See for example Srivastava, *A course on Borel sets*, [Theorem 4.1.5, p.130](http://books.google.com/books?id=FhYGYJtMwcUC&pg=PA130).

A clever refinement of this argument yields the answer to your question:

> Let $U \subset [0,1] \times [0,1]$ be an analytic set which is universal for the analytic sets in $[0,1]$. Then $U$ is *not* an element of the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{P}[0,1] \times \mathcal{L}[0,1]$ of the power set $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{P}[0,1]$ and the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{L}[0,1]$.
>
> In particular, being analytic, $U$ is universally measurable in $[0,1]^2$, but it does not even belong to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{L}[0,1] \times \mathcal{L}[0,1] \supset  \mathcal{B}([0,1])^u \times \mathcal{B}([0,1])^u$.

This is proved in B.V. Rao, [Remarks on analytic sets](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm66/fm66126.pdf), Fund. Math., 66 (1970), 237-239. A variant was independently found by R. Mansfield in the first part of [The solution to one of Ulam's problems concerning analytic sets, I and II](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1970-0279265-6) by different and more complicated methods (the argument in the second part is essentially the same as the one given by Rao). Srivastava's book, [Theorem 4.3.4, page 141](http://books.google.com/books?id=FhYGYJtMwcUC&pg=PA141) also contains a proof of this. Of course, one can replace $[0,1]$ by $\mathbb{R}$ or any other uncountable Polish space.

Further elaborations and refinements can be found in Arnold W. Miller's [Measurable rectangles](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9211206). See in particular Theorem 1 where he proves that $\mathcal{L}[0,1]$ can be replaced by the Baire property algebra $\mathcal{BP}[0,1]$ in the Mansfield-Rao theorem.

Moreover, Miller showed in section 4 of [On the length of Borel hierarchies](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/hier.pdf) that it is relatively consistent with ZFC that no universal analytic set belongs to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{P}[0,1] \times \mathcal{P}[0,1]$.